# Bad URI Ruby on Rails: is it because long?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, uri

So I have a website that's fully working, with some URI encoded in the URL.

however, when I try to pass the URL to my chrome browser:

`http://somewhere:3000/find/someOne?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=someThing&choicen=no&querys={%22peopleName%22%3A%22%22%2C%22peopleGroup%22%3A%22%22%2C%22place%22%3A%22%22%2C%22pip%22%3A%22%22%2C%22hw%22%3A%22%22%2C%22somerock%22%3A%22%22%2C%22rocksomerock%22%3A%22%22%2C%22diedAt%22%3A%222016-01-01%20-%202016-12-31%22%2C%22borndAt%22%3A%22%22%2C%22taxRate%22%3A%22%22}`

-- it throws me an error in the browser:

```
Bad Request

bad URI `/find/someOne?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=someThing&choicen=no&querys={%22peopleName%22%3A%22%22%2C%22peopleGroup%22%3A%22%22%2C%22place%22%3A%22%22%2C%22pip%22%3A%22%22%2C%22hw%22%3A%22%22%2C%22somerock%22%3A%22%22%2C%22rocksomerock%22%3A%22%22%2C%22diedAt%22%3A%222016-01-01%20-%202016-12-31%22%2C%22borndAt%22%3A%22%22%2C%22taxRate%22%3A%22%22}'.

WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.3/2014-11-13) at somewhere.com:3000
```

Also shows `[2016-07-04 18:11:31] ERROR bad URI` in the rails console

Versions:

- rails3
- Ruby 1.9.3

Any idea how to get it working? Is it because the `{` and `}` in the URI or because it is too long?

Comment: I'd first try uuencoding the `{`/`}` and seeing if that fixes it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code. Also, please clarify your question. What do you mean by "when I try to paste the URL"? Paste it where?

Answer (score 1):

Parse the path in the controller upon incoming request, using `Rack::Utils#parse_nested_query`, see: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/Rack/Utils.parse_nested_query

```
# config/routes.rb

get '/find/someOne/*str' => 'find#someOne'


# app/controllers/find_controller.rb

class FindController < ApplicationController
  def someOne
    custom_params = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query(request.env['ORIGINAL_FULLPATH'])
    querys_hash = JSON.parse(custom_params["querys"])
  end
end
```

Example via console:

```
$ bundle exec rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 31944
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.0)
irb(main):001:0> custom_params = Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query "utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=someThing&choicen=no&querys={%22peopleName%22%3A%22%22%2C%22peopleGroup%22%3A%22%22%2C%22place%22%3A%22%22%2C%22pip%22%3A%22%22%2C%22hw%22%3A%22%22%2C%22somerock%22%3A%22%22%2C%22rocksomerock%22%3A%22%22%2C%22diedAt%22%3A%222016-01-01%20-%202016-12-31%22%2C%22borndAt%22%3A%22%22%2C%22taxRate%22%3A%22%22}"
=> {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"someThing", "choicen"=>"no", "querys"=>"{\"peopleName\":\"\",\"peopleGroup\":\"\",\"place\":\"\",\"pip\":\"\",\"hw\":\"\",\"somerock\":\"\",\"rocksomerock\":\"\",\"diedAt\":\"2016-01-01 - 2016-12-31\",\"borndAt\":\"\",\"taxRate\":\"\"}"}
irb(main):002:0> querys_hash = JSON.parse custom_params["querys"]
=> {"peopleName"=>"", "peopleGroup"=>"", "place"=>"", "pip"=>"", "hw"=>"", "somerock"=>"", "rocksomerock"=>"", "diedAt"=>"2016-01-01 - 2016-12-31", "borndAt"=>"", "taxRate"=>""}
```